# file_exists() not working in php5 inside while loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, get

file_exists isn't working. I've looked at a few examples and still no go. Program does not detect the file. The path of my file is /var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/recording.mp3 and the website root is inside osbs. The location of this file is inside PHPAPI that is why I do not put full path in file_put_contents. The program is able to make the original recording.mp3 but not any appended versions of it.

```
<?php
$actual_name = pathinfo("PHPAPI/recording.mp3",PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo("PHPAPI/recording.mp3",PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($_GET["RecordingUrl"]) {
     if (file_exists("/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/".$actual_name.".".$extension)) {
        $actual_name = find_new_name($original_name, $extension);
     }
     else {
        $actual_name = $original_name;
     }
     $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
     file_put_contents($name, file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"]));
}

function find_new_name ( $file, $extension ) {
    $name = $file.".".$extension;
    $i = 0;
    while(file_exists("/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/".$name)){
        $new_name = $file.$i;
        $name = $new_name.".".$extension;
        $i++;
    }
    return $new_name;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: This is a huge security issue: `file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"])`

Comment: @greg0ire I know it's only for testing. I would normally use $_POST

Comment: You're hilarious

Comment: Passing file_get_contents() any user input directly is a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the `file_put_contents`. You need to specify a full path, and you only specify a file name. Try `echo`ing `$name` just before using it, you'll see it's not a path, just a filename.

I would recommend you to set a constant at the begining of the file with the path instead of sometimes relying on relative paths and sometimes relying on absolute paths.

```
<?php
const SAVE_PATH = "/var/www/osbs/";

$actual_name = pathinfo(SAVE_PATH."PHPAPI/recording.mp3",PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo(SAVE_PATH."PHPAPI/recording.mp3",PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (isset($_GET["RecordingUrl"]) && $_GET["RecordingUrl"]) {
     if (file_exists(SAVE_PATH."PHPAPI/".$actual_name.".".$extension)) {
        $actual_name = find_new_name($original_name, $extension);
     }
     else {
        $actual_name = $original_name;
     }
     $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;

     file_put_contents(SAVE_PATH.'PHPAPI/'.$name, file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"]));
}

function find_new_name ( $file, $extension ) {
    $name = $file.".".$extension;
    $i = 0;
    while(file_exists(SAVE_PATH."PHPAPI/".$name)){
        $new_name = $file.$i;
        $name = $new_name.".".$extension;
        $i++;
    }
    return $new_name;
}
 ?>
```

What I changed:

1. Defined a `const SAVE_PATH = "/var/www/osbs/";`
2. Use the new constant everywhere. No more relative sometimes and absolute sometimes, it's all absolute.
3. Used the constant in `file_put_contents` (**THIS IS THE ACTUAL FIX, YOU NEED A FULL PATH HERE**)
4. Added an additional check to make sure `RecordingUrl` isset, otherwise you get a PHP warning when it's not set.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about the path? `/PHPAPI` looks for the file inside `/PHPAPI`, not the expected `/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/`. You should check for `PHPAPI/$filename` instead.

Comment: /var/www/osbs/PHPAPI is the full path if you were to SSH into the server, however, apache document root for this domain is osbs folder. so /PHPAPI is the folder and recording.mp3 is the original file it should look for. /PHPAPI/recording.mp3 is the path. If the original file does not exist then create it from $_GET but if it does exist then append a counter number to it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16357314)

Comment: @ShawnMehan I'm answering Taluses answer very clearly.

Comment: On the `file_exists`, it doesn't care for the apache root (actually, no functions in php really care for this : think CLI, Apache, Nginx and all sorts of other supports). You need to use the real root path, which is the one you ssh into (to simplify).

Comment: @ShawnMehan If this is indeed not really an answer, it's more a pointer to it. And part of my text is the answer too. Not really a critique or a request for clarification...

Comment: @Talus this is not true, PHP script takes the Apache webroot of the domain. If this is the case the file wouldn't be created to begin with.

Comment: Once again, no. `file_exists` doesn't care about that. whatever is in the url address doesn't matter to php. Try `__DIR__`, which is the full path to the directory containing the current file, and it will _not_ give you `/`, but `/var/www/osbs`. _all_ the file functions in PHP are working about the same : it needs the _real_ path (or relative path from the current script, to simplify). `realpath('/PHPAPI/...')` shoud return `null` or something like that, no the path you expect, while `realpath(__DIR__ . '/PHPAPI/...`) will return the path you expect.

It's the same thing for `file_exists`.

Comment: php is a general purpose language, your code could work from the CLI, which obviously does not know about your document root. You learn about how paths differ from urls

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the first line of your script:

```
$actual_name = pathinfo("PHPAPI/recording.mp3", PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

This will assign `recording.mp3` to `$actual_filename`. You are then checking for `recording.mp3.mp3` by concatenating the extension to the filename. I think you want to use `PATHINFO_BASENAME` which will return the filename sans extension.

Comment: This does not help. Even if I change the path to (file_exists("/PHPAPI/recording.mp3")) file_exists still fails

Comment: It’s likely that your [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) doesn’t contain the directory which contains the folder PHPAPI. Dump out get_include_path to get a list of directories it’ll look in to find the folder, if the root directory isn’t in there you’ll need to add it first or use the full path to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your all logical in the `find_new_name()` function. That would made your code clearer

```
if ($_GET["RecordingUrl"]) {
  $name = find_new_name("PHPAPI/recording.mp3");
  file_put_contents($name, file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"]));
}

function find_new_name($name) {
  $info = pathinfo($name);
  $name = $info['basename'];
  $i = 0;
  while (file_exists("$info[dirname]/$name")) {
    $name = sprintf('%s%d.%s', $info['filename'], ++$i, $info['extension']);
  }
  return "$info[dirname]/$name";
}
```

Comment: Only answer pointing this out, I'd say this is the major culprit. Sane functions FTW. However I must admit, this can be further improved so that an existing number in the filename can be re-used and in case a file is created after detected free (e.g. parallel uploads) the function can continue to find the *next* new name.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused between **URL** of a file and its **PATH**

Your httdoc(or public_html ) root is **/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI**

But Your filesystem root is '**/**'

**Try**

```
file_put_contents( __DIR__.'/'.$name, file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"]));
```

there are lots of bad practices in your code

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the path with the file_put_contents().
It should be:

```
file_put_contents("PHPAPI/".$name, file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"]));
```

Or:

```
file_put_contents("/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/".$name, file_get_contents($_GET["RecordingUrl"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

'file_exists' and a few other file calls like fstat are cached by php. This is documented in the manual for file_exists. Your first call when the file does not exists is saved and returned in subsequent calls. Use 'clearstatcache()' between calls to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

A "little" refactoring:

1. Absolute path everywhere
2. Transparent function, more self-explanatory name, simpler use of argument
3. Protection against malicious input ($_POST really doesn't cut it)
4. Why file_put_contents() when you want to actually copy()

   ```
   <?php

   define("SRC_PATH", "/var/www/osbs/whereverYourSrcIs/");
   define("SAVE_PATH", "/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/");

   function findAvailableName($name) {
       $i = 1;
       $pathinfo = pathinfo($name);
       while(file_exists($name)) {
           $name = $pathinfo['dirname'] . '/' . $pathinfo['filename'] . "." . $i++ . "." . $pathinfo['extension'];
       }
       return $name;
   }

   if (isset($_GET["RecordingUrl"]) && $_GET["RecordingUrl"]) {

       if (strpos('/' . $_GET['RecordingUrl'] . '/', '/../') !== false) {
           die("invalid input, don't be evil");
       }

       copy(SRC_PATH . $_GET["RecordingUrl"], findAvailableName(SAVE_PATH . "recording.mp3"));
   }
   ```